# When I clear it and add another item to my shopping cart, the item that I cleared come again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code I used for my shopping cart. When I use this code the problem is that when I click the clear button, and then I add another item, the previous Item that I cleared came back

I have tried to move around the saveCart function so it will properly do its job, but there are still no progress in solving the problem

This is the buttons to buy the Item ( I only show the button since probably the effect is only at here )

```
<input type="button" name="" value="B U Y" class="buyBut add-to-cart" data-name="Avocado & Brownie Cake" data-price="150000">

<input type="button" name="" value="B U Y" class="buyBut add-to-cart" data-name="Strawberry & Watermelon Cake" data-price="65000">
```

---

This is the space to show the items and the clear button

```
<table id="show-cart">
 <br>
</table>
 <br>
<button id="clear-cart" onClick="clearCart()">Clear Cart</button>
```

---

This is the JQuery ( I use JQuery 3.3.1.min )

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
 var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));
 addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
 displayCart();
 });

function displayCart(){
 var cartArray = listCart();
 var output ="";
 for (var i in cartArray){
   output +=
 "<tr>"
 +"<td class='itemName'>"
 +cartArray[i].name
 +"</td>"
 +"<td class='itemPrice'>"
 +"Rp "
 +cartArray[i].price
 +"</td>"
 +"<td>"
 +"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
 +"</td>"
 +"<td class='itemCount'>"
 +cartArray[i].count
 +"</td>"
 +"<td style='width:20px;'>"
 +"</td>"
 +"<td>"
 +"<span class='sub-item' data-name='"+cartArray[i].name+"'>-</span>"
 +"</td>"
 +"<td style='width:12px;'>"
 +"</td>"
 +"<td>"
 +"<span class='delete-item' data-name='"+cartArray[i].name+"'>&times;</span>"
 +"</td>"
 +"</tr>"
  }

 $("#show-cart").html(output);
 $("#total-cart").html( totalCart() );
 $("#cart-count").html( countCart() );
 saveCart();
}

$("#show-cart").on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
 var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
 removeItemFromCartAll(name);
 displayCart();
});

$("#show-cart").on("click", ".sub-item", function(event) {
 var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
 removeItemFromCart(name);
 displayCart();
});
```

---

This is the Javascript

```
 var cart = [];

 var Item = function(name, price, count){
     this.name = name;
     this.price = price;
     this.count = count;
 }

 // adding item to cart
 function addItemToCart(name, price, count) {
     for (var i in cart) {
       if (cart[i].name === name ) {
         cart[i].count += count;
         return;
       }
     }
     var item = new Item(name, price, count);
     cart.push(item);
     saveCart();
 }

 // Removes 1 Item From Cart
 function removeItemFromCart(name){
   for (var i in cart) {
     if (cart[i].name === name){
       cart[i].count --;
         if (cart[i].count === 0){
           cart.splice(i, 1)
         }
       break;
     }
   }
   saveCart();
 }

 // Clear 1 Object From Cart
 function removeItemFromCartAll(name){
   for (var i in cart) {
     if (cart[i].name === name){
       cart.splice(i,1);
       break;
     }
   }
   saveCart();
 }

 // Clear The Cart
 function clearCart(){
   cart = [];
   document.getElementById("show-cart").innerHTML = "";
   saveCart();
   document.getElementById("total-cart").innerHTML = "0";
 }

 // Shows Total Count Of Item
 function countCart(){
   var totalCount = 0;
   for (var i in cart){
       totalCount += cart[i].count;
   }
   return totalCount;
 }

 // Shows Total Price
 function totalCart(){
   var totalCost = 0;
   for (var i in cart){
     totalCost += cart[i].price * cart[i].count
   }
   return totalCost;
   saveCart();
 }
 // Returns an array
 function listCart(){
   var cartCopy = [];
   for (var i in cart){
     var item = cart[i];
     var itemCopy = {};
     for (var p in item){
        itemCopy[p] = item[p];
     }
     cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
   }
   return cartCopy;
 }

 function saveCart(){
   localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
 }

 function loadCart(){
   cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
 }

loadCart();
displayCart();
```

I expected the output that when the clear button is clicked, and I add an item, the item shown is only 1 and the previous item in the cart before I clicked is gone.

Comment: many error in your **long** code,  please use your debugger (F12) before

Comment: please, make a return on my answer, or should I think that it is null and that work has been useless?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not read your code, there is too much to say, and I guess your mistake comes from bad management on the addressing of tables and their elements.

I adapted one of my old code to match it to your work; this is a big technical gap for you, but I think it will be useful for you to program on better rails :)

HTML part:
`

```
<div id="Bt_BUY">
    <button data-price="150000"  >Avocado & Brownie Cake</button>
    <button data-price="65000"  >Strawberry & Watermelon Cake</button>
</div>

<table id="show-cart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button id="clear-cart" >Clear Cart</button>
```

`

JS part
`

```
"use strict"

const Buy_obj = {
  List : [],
  DisplayTable : null,

  add( x_name, x_price, x_count ) {

    let idx = this.List.findIndex( e=>e.name=== x_name);

    if (idx>=0)
      { this.List[idx].count += x_count; }
    else
      { this.List.push( { 'name' : x_name, 'price' : x_price, 'count' : x_count } ) }

    this.saveList();
    this.drawTable();
  }
  ,
  clear(){ 
    this.List.length = 0;

    this.saveList();
    this.drawTable();
  }
  ,
  remove( x_name ) {
    let idx = this.List.findIndex( e=>e.name=== x_name);

    if (idx>=0) {
      this.List[idx].count--;
      if (this.List[idx].count <= 0) 
        {  this.List.splice(idx,1) }
    }
    this.saveList();
    this.drawTable();
  }
  ,
  saveList() {
    localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(this.List));
  }
  ,
  loadList() {
    let ls_list = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart");
    if ( ls_list)
      { this.List = JSON.parse(ls_list); }
  }
  ,
  initialise( $xTable ) {
    this.DisplayTable = $xTable;

    this.loadList();
    this.drawTable();
  }
  ,
  drawTable() {
    this.DisplayTable.innerHTML = "";

    this.List.forEach(e=>{
      let
        T_row  = this.DisplayTable.insertRow(-1),
        T_cell_0 = T_row.insertCell(0),
        T_cell_1 = T_row.insertCell(1),
        T_cell_2 = T_row.insertCell(2);

        T_cell_0.textContent = e.name;
        T_cell_1.textContent = e.price;
        T_cell_2.textContent = e.count;
    })
  }
}

//  *************************** Main *****************************

Buy_obj.initialise ( document.querySelector('#show-cart tbody')  );


document.querySelector('#Bt_BUY').onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
  e.stopPropagation();

  Buy_obj.add( e.target.textContent, e.target.dataset.price, 1 );
}

document.querySelector('#clear-cart').onclick = function(e) {
  Buy_obj.clear();
}
```

`